# Adding SVG Defs Outside of the SVG Tag

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to use SVG Defs outside of the SVG Tag.  Something like this:

```
<defs>
    // defs code goes here
</defs>

<svg>
// svg code goes here
</svg>
```

If so -- how can I associate the `defs` tag with the particular `svg` tag that I want to target?

Comment: Basically...no. I'm not clear on what it is you are trying to achieve. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs

Comment: I am using react-icons -- it creates svg icons.  I would like to use linearGradients with those icons -- but the code that is output lacks a `defs` tag.  So I was thinking/hoping that I could create my own tag and associate it with the svg code that is output.

Comment: The link I provided shows how this is implemented.

Comment: You can add svg defs in a different svg element. This svg element may be very small and with `position:absolute`, so that it doesn't affect the layout

Comment: @Paulie_D As far as I can tell -- that link shows what you originally said -- that it CANNOT be done.  Is that correct?

Comment: @enxaneta  How can I add a defs in a DIFFERENT svg element and use it to color THE OTHER svg element?

Comment: Please take a look at this answer where the patterns are in a different svg element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531434/hidding-svg-affects-other-svg-styles-in-the-same-page/56791893#56791893

Comment: No...once defined in the initial SVG the defs can be used by any other SVG. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WqKZLb

Comment: @Paulie_D But I do need to add `<use...>` within the `svg` tag -- is that correct?

Comment: @Moshe Nope = https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WqKZLb

Comment: @Paulie_D Got it -- thanks.  I'm going to try it out now.

Answer (score 2):

## YES

At least *outside THAT svg* element, which, i think, is what you're going after?!

### IT ONLY NEEDS TO BE **INSIDE any SVG** TAGS

but those don't have to be more than `<svg style="display:none;"><defs>...</defs></svg>`

(It doesn't matter if it's defined afterwards or before and can even be written outside the body (although i'm not sure that'd be valid html).)

Comment: without the ```display:none``` it creates an empty space (in my code at least)